# Можно ли через php писать js файлы?

Tags: php, javascript

Можно ли через php писать js файлы?

Например фал lost.js.php

Содержит

```
    function load() {
       document.getElementById('button_my').onclick = function () {
       document.getElementById('my').innerHTML = '' + '<div class="bottom_homo"><div class="fosts" ><div class="sorsal"><?php echo 'fdsaf'; ?></div></div>';
       document.getElementById('choise_area').setAttribute("class", "choise_area1");
return false;
}
```

}

В чем минусы этого?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если кэширование выставить - минусов нет. Таким способом иногда собирают все js-файлы проекта в один для снижения кол-ва запросов.

Иногда также используется для формирования js с использованием сессии, куков и пр.

Comment: +1 если только использовать для склеивания уже готовых js файлов. Но не так, чтобы по всей серверной части кусками раскидать клиентский код. 

Или если организовать таким способом подгрузку модулей для огромного проекта.

Comment: куки читаются нативным javascript'ом на ура, для всего остального есть ajax, лично я придерживаюсь мнения что это полный бред и так делать не хорошо :)

Если javascript'a много и, тем более, если над ним работает несколько разработчиков, это проявляется на ура, сборку в 1 большой код осуществляют в самом конце.

К сожалению такой подход используется не иногда, а крайне часто и это, на самом деле, очень и очень прискорбно

Comment: @AlexWindHope это еще удобно для сторонних сервисов, которые на лету контент подгружают и юзают сессии например, вот с этим лично сталкивался (и сейчас сталкиваюсь). Сервисы имеются в виду типа того же openid, только с профилями-настройками-аватарками, в куки все не всунешь.

Comment: Это исключение из правила, любое деструктивное действие в некоторых случаях оправдано, но никак не в общем

Answer (score 0):

Наверное надо писать

```
echo "function load(){...}";
```

Comment: Совсем не обязательно, надо просто отдавать верный js и желательно на всякий случай вставить

<? header('Content-Type: text/javascript; charset=utf8');?>

Answer (score 0):

Можно, но метод древний еще в начале века так писали.

Основной минус, который я вижу это то, что у Вас и серверный код, и разметка, и клиентский код всё вперемешку. Отсюда будут проблемы при масштабировании и в конце концов Вы сами запутаетесь в своем коде.